# Search text containing a new line in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that stores a large number of products. By some mistakes i added some of the product name with a new line. I need to find them. The bellow query is not listing all of the expected data.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "\r\n";
```

Comment: after finding, do you want to remove that characters?

Comment: No,I just want to select the id.

Comment: just execute sql - 
SELECT id FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "[\n\r]";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depend of way what you use to new line.
Different text editor programs use different way to write new line.

Try to use only "\n" or combinations of "\r" and "\n".

For me worked this:

```
  SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "\n";
```

Comment: It may not work for line separator `\r` (MacOS 9 and older)

Answer (score 2):

Line separator varies OS to OS i.e. `\n` (Linux and MacOS X), `\r` (MacOS 9 and older) and `\r\n` (Windows)).

So you could try as bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "\n" OR `product_name` REGEXP "\r";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "\n" or `product_name` REGEXP "\r";
```

Comment: It may not work for line separator `\r` (MacOS 9 and older)

Comment: @rev_dihazum Updated my anwer

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f74000/2

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "\n";
```

should work in most cases

Answer (score 0):

Following select query must work for you

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` REGEXP "[\n\r]";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product_name` LIKE '%\\n\\r%';
```

I come from Oracle background and found easier this form (it works for me with MySql 5.6 on Aws)
Hope this could help someone stumbling here in the future :)